# How to make "Donate" feature that would work without getting my app suspended?

Tags: android, paypal, in-app-billing

I'm developing an app in which i'm planning to add a donate feature, but googling about it, found that when using paypal or other 3rd party for this feature attracts google to suspend you're app.

How to implement a Donate feature and also make sure that google doesn't suspend my app?

If any option any example with same would also help me in ways.
if paypal an example link or if google wallet an example.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about legal requirements of a marketplace, not about programming or tools.

Comment: @GabeSechan I've edited the question seeking an example as well.

Answer (score 0):

A common thing I see a lot is to make 2 versions of your app, 1 free and 1 donate version. Or heck, you could just use Google Play In-app Billing and offer some kind of small extra feature for the payment.

Comment: So, only through google play in app billing it is possible to make the feature and also make sure the app doesn't get suspended ?